# how to unit test a simple tcp client/server on one local machine/host?

Tags: c++, sockets, testing

I am currently wrapping BSD sockets for the first time and also unit test my results along the way. Anyways I came across a problem while writing a simple test to test my Acceptor and TcpSocket class which is related to reusing the local host address, i.e.

Pseudocode:

```
//server thread
{
    //binds, listens and accepts on port 50716 on localhost
    TcpAcceptor acceptor(Resolver::fromService("50716"));
    //i get a ECONNREFUSED error inside the accept function when trying to create newSock
    TcpSocket newSock = acceptor.accept();
}

//connect in the main thread
TcpSocket connectionSocket(Resolver::resolve(Resolver::Query("localhost", "50716")));
```

Is it even possible to listen and connect on the same host/port? Is there any way to run a simple client/server test on the same machine/host?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Cool, things work now! Just for reference, I also noticed in the process that you don't even need to use a thread, even if you use blocking sockets to perform a simple test, if you decouple listen from accept like this:

```
//server socket
TcpAcceptor acceptor;
acceptor.bind(Resolver::fromService("0"));
acceptor.listen();

//client socket, blocks until connection is established
TcpSocket clientSock(SocketAddress("127.0.0.1", acceptor.address().port()));

//accept the connection, blocks until one accept is done
TcpSocket connectionSock = acceptor.accept();

//send a test message to the client
size_t numBytesSent = connectionSock.send(ByteArray("Hello World!"));

//read the message on the client socket
ByteArray msg(12);
size_t bytesReceived = clientSock.receive(msg);
std::cout<<"Num Bytes received: "<<bytesReceived<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Message: "<<msg<<std::endl;
```

building the tests like this allows for nice and simple test cases even for the blocking functions.

Comment: I don't think what you're attempting is possible. What you should do is instead separate behaviours from the packets that trigger them, then write test cases that test each behaviour independently of how they were invoked. You can then test the TCP layer with a tool you write / borrow, which should be much easier if your code is structured correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There is no such restriction that a server and a client must be different processes. One thread can open/listen a socket and other thread can connect to it.

Comment: hey thanks, it actually works now! The problem was that the newly created socket in my accept function tried to connect, even though it was already connected. thanks for clarifying, brought me on the right track!

Comment: With an asynchronous network library you can do it all in the same thread, which is MUCH easier to test.

Comment: i know that. i am writing my own though, and using a thread basically tests the blocking versions of the functions.